# Can't upload beta build to TestFlight via Fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, macos-sierra, xcode9, fastlane

I'm trying to upload beta build to TestFlight via Fastlane. It compiles fine but uploading ends with the following pattern:

```
[20:32:00]: Successfully uploaded the new binary to iTunes Connect
[20:32:00]: If you want to skip waiting for the processing to be finished, use the `skip_waiting_for_build_processing` option
[20:32:03]: Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build (1.9.12 - 4)
[20:32:34]: Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build (1.9.12 - 4)
[20:33:05]: Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build (1.9.12 - 4)
[20:33:36]: Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build (1.9.12 - 4)
[20:34:07]: Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build (1.9.12 - 4)
[20:34:38]: Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again
[20:35:09]: Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again
[20:35:40]: Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again
[20:36:11]: Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again
[20:36:43]: Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again
...
```

And the last line continues to show up for 30 minutes until I killed the process.
This build didn't appear in iTunes Connect.

Then I tried to build and upload manually via Application Loader. It shows success result but build didn't show up in iTunes Connect even after hour of waiting.

Could anyone give me some guidance?

I use:

- macOS Sierra
- XCode 9
- fastlane 2.61.0

Answer (score 0):

It's still "processing"? sometimes it's still even a full day in this state.

Sometimes, it's upload successfull but something internally fails and this build doesn't shows, but if you try to upload another time it throws an error.

This build already exists, but not in iTunes...
My recomendation, upload your ipa, and wait (more than 30min) wait and wait, you should see your file "processing" on itunes and later it will pass.

As extra info, you could avoid the waiting step if you pass `pilot upload -z` param.
More info on your console: `fastlane pilot upload --help`